# jquery, add active class to links

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu, addclass

Hi i'm working on a off canvas menu and I want to add a class to highlight active menu item but the jquery code I'm currently working with does not seem to add the class to the active link. I tried all potential solutions I came across in the web and nothing seem to work. Any suggestions, ideas, resources?

```
<nav class="site-menu">
       <div class="menu-list"> 
        <ul>
            <li><a href="portfolio.php">portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="projects.php">projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="process.php">process</a></li>
            <li><a href="blog.php">blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.php">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

css

```
 .site-menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 0;
}

.site-menu ul li a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: #7f7f7f;
    background: transparent;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.menu-list{
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans',     sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px; 
    text-align: left;
     }

.active {
    color:#fff;
}
```

script

```
var selector = ".site-menu li";

$(selector).click(function(){
    $(selector).removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: When you click on anchor, a redirection is made so a new page is loaded. Not clear what you are expecting here

Comment: @A.Wolff is actually makes a point I missed. How do you expect to set active class if the page is redirected? Or it's prevented somehow?

Answer (score 3):

You need to make CSS selector more specific:

```
.site-menu ul li.active a {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Otherwise the rule `.site-menu ul li a` has higher precedence.

Read on the subject: [CSS Specificity: Things You Should Know](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/).

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6ck1Lg0w/

Comment: No internal links are used in OP code, it could be part of his issue

Comment: You are right, I made it for the sake of the demo. But I assume that the issue OP has is CSS not redirect issue. Otherwise the question makes little sense.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var selector = ".site-menu li";

selector.click(function(){
    selector.removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your selector to the following one:

```
var selector = ".site-menu ul li a";
```

Answer (score 0):

When you load a new page the javascript changes will be lost. But you can check what page is `active` when the page is loaded like this:

JS

```
(function($){
    $('.site-menu li a').each(function(){
        if( $(this).attr('href') == window.location.pathname ) $(this).addClass('active');
    })
})
```